# Cant find Ubuntu 14.04 LTS machine on local network from Windows 7 machine

Tags: networking

I recently installed the Windows file sharing service on my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS machine. However after restarting my session, and even a reboot (which was not requested), I am still unable to locate my Ubuntu machine on my local network from my Windows 7 machine. It just doesn't show up in "Network". On a related note, I have no problem browsing my Windows 7 machines from Ubuntu. Curious. What might be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try clicking the windows 'bubble' in the lower left of the Win 7 machine screen and typing

\\ubuntu-machine-name  (of course, replacing 'ubuntu-machine-name' with your machine's name)

in the search box.

If the Ubuntu machine is truly reachable it should open a File Explorer window showing the shared folders on that Ubuntu machine.

Comment: Excellent. This indeed works. However, my machine still does not show up under the more conventional Network area of Windows Explorer. I wonder if there is a way  to make it visible there, so I'm not having to type out my machine name manually every time I need to access it. Thank you for the reply.

Comment: Perhaps I should ask this as another question altogether, but now that I've accessed my shared folders on my Ubuntu machine, I can't figure out how to log in. I've tried all relevant password/username combinations, and nothing seems to work. What do you make of this (and should I ask a separate question?)?

Comment: You may have to qualify your login by specifying the name of the machine before you give your username. enter \ubuntu-machine-name\userid in the login box that pops up on the Windows machine when you try to access the shared folder. Use a userid (and password in the next field) that works on ubuntu-machine-name.   Once you can access the shared folders, you should be able to create Windows shortcuts to them. So then you could access the folders via the shortcuts instead of having to type in the machine name in the search box.